# Unable to consume WCF service (hosted in IIS )

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have hosted my web-application in IIS 5 in a virtual directory. 
When browsing `.aspx web pages` everything works fine. Web-page takes few inputs from user and invokes WCF services. On making the service call I get below exception -

> There was an error in serializing body of message : 'Unable to
>   generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS2001: Source file
>   'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\peqft5u5.0.cs' could not be found error CS2008: No
>   inputs specified '

I have double checked environment variables looks good in the server.
I can confirm, there is no problem in code since, same works perfectly fine in other box of similar configuration & hosting environment.

Comment: Does the designated user the service is running under have read/write access to your c:\windows\temp folder? That's the first thing I'd look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET default user was not having write access to TEMP folder. Posting the answer in hope it would be helpful later, some day!